# Centre Image and Div Underlay in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm attempting to centre an image and div layer inside a containing div, but so far I can't get it to move from the left of the column. I've tried a few different ways but just can't get it to move. Even the margin auto trick isn't working, which I suspect is because bootstrap 4 is a flex box now.

**HTML**:

```css
#user-avatar {
    background: #ff4e00;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

#user img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 250px;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

#user-avatar:hover img {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.middle {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.middle i {
    font-size: 34px;
}

#user-avatar:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="user" class="col-12">
    <div class="col-12" id="user-avatar">
        <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="assets/users/av-lg/liane.png" />
        <div class="middle">
            <i class="fas fa-camera-alt"></i>
            <p>Edit Avatar</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="username" class="text-center"><span>Howdy </span>Liane</p>
    <div id="xp-bar" class="text-left">
        <div id="xp"><p><i class="fas fa-stars"></i> XP</p></div>
    </div>
    <p id="stats" class="text-right">Level 1</p>
</div>
```

It's the image and the 'underlay' ('middle' div) that I need to be in the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%)` to `#user-avatar`. check below link.
thank you

http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/10994/

Answer (score 0):

Add Class on `id="user-avatar"` to `mx-auto`

```
<div class="col-12 mx-auto" id="user-avatar">
        <img class="d-block" src="assets/users/av-lg/liane.png" />
        <div class="middle">
            <i class="fas fa-camera-alt"></i>
            <p>Edit Avatar</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/v06j8orn/9/

Comment: Still to the left :(

Answer (score 0):

simply add this style - centrd now

```
#user-avatar {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```